# How to have 2 different projects with the same package name in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app that has been published in Play Store. Now, I need to develop new features while at the same time to do some bug fixings. How to have 2 different projects with the same package name in Android Studio? So the not-ready new feature development won't overlap with the bug fixings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source version control such as git is exactly what you want. In your case, you can branch out from the base code and can make some changes with no effect on the main code.

Comment: I ended up copying the whole folder with Windows Explorer then rename the folder. Everything else remains the same. Then open both folders (projects) with AS. So far so good. Not sure if there will be problem in the future or not.